Is there any method of uploading a file downloaded using requests to AWS using boto3 without writing to a temporary file?
I'm currently working with some Python code which does the following:

uses requests to download a file from the web
saves the contents to a temporary file on disk
uses the boto3 library to upload this file to an AWS S3 bucket
in more detail: requests.get collects the data in memory first, then file.write(response.content) writes this data out to disk

This is seeminly quite inefficient, since there is no reason to write the data to disk. The temporary file is deleted once the data has been uploaded to S3.
Is there a way to use the boto3 library to more efficiently, and cut out this writing to disk step?
The documentation for boto3 is a bit limited. It doesn't look like the API supports this, but perhaps (I hope) I'm wrong. (It's a large file...)

Yes, you can upload from memory:
import requests
import boto3

web_page_content = requests.get('https://google.com').text

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.put_object(Bucket='my-bucket', Key='file_name', Body=web_page_content)


Thanks for your answer - is there a way to do this using a session object? In other words, if I create boto3_session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key) and pass around a reference to boto3_session can I call some similar or equivalent function to put_object. Btw, do you have any tips for how to find documentation for boto3? The AWS docs are quite minimal

You can use: session.client('s3')

I find the boto3 documentation to be excellent, especially the code examples towards the bottom of each page.

Just on that particular point, unless you already know put_object exists, there is no way to find it from the docs. I read the Quickstart, Sample Tutorial, Code Examples, and some of the Developer Guide pages, and didn't find this. Look at this page and tell me this is an example of a good documentation: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/index.html

Some doc pages like sqlalchemy are dense and require a lot of reading before you can do anything. This is an example of the opposite: The amount of information required is small, it's just impossible to find what you want, unless you know in advance what to look for.

FYI, to generate the above code, I requested it from an AI and then cut it down to the basics. I find that AIs are quite good at coding against AWS services.

I've found the same thing - using ChatGPT 4o. I personally find it a bit upsetting that ChatGPT can find the answers and I can't. (From reading the official docs.) This is not good. We have no idea what the source of ChatGPT's information it. It could be a set of public Github repositories.
